# How to merge multiple router via gin before run

Tags: go, routes, go-gin

Lets say I have some routes in a `subemenuRoutes.go` file like this:

```
package routes

import(
    "github.com/IamFrost/api-5/pkg/middlewares"

    "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
)

// GetSubMenuRoutes return a group of routes for login
func GetSubMenuRoutes() *gin.Engine{
    router := gin.Default()
    menuRoutes := router.Group("/submenu")
    {
        getRoutes := menuRoutes.Group("/get")
        {
            getRoutes.GET("/getallsubmenus", middlewares.GetAllSubMenus)
        }
    }
    return router
}
```

And I am running them from `main.go` like this :

```
package main

import(
    "fmt"

    "github.com/IamFrost/api-5/pkg/routes"

    "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
    "github.com/gin-contrib/cors"
)

func main(){
    
    fmt.Println("from main")

    router := gin.Default()

    router = routes.GetSubMenuRoutes()
    
    router.Use(cors.Default())
    router.Run(":3000")
}
```

Up to this, all working.

Now my question is :

lets say I have some other routes in a file `menuRoutes.go` :

```
package routes

import(
    "github.com/IamFrost/api-5/pkg/middlewares"

    "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
)

// GetMenuRoutes return a group of routes for login
func GetMenuRoutes() *gin.Engine{
    router := gin.Default()
    menuRoutes := router.Group("/menu")
    {
        getRoutes := menuRoutes.Group("/get")
        {
            getRoutes.GET("/getallmenus", middlewares.GetAllMenus)
        }
    }
    return router
}
```

Now, I want to run both **menu routes** and **submenu routes** from main .

But In my `main.go` , you see, I did this before running,

```
router = routes.GetSubMenuRoutes()
```

So How Can I merge all routes coming from `routes.GetSubMenuRoutes()` and `routes.GetMenuRoutes()`

before I call `router.Run` in `main.go`?

Update:

As their doc said I wanted something like this in `main.go`, But my routes are coming from function. You see : I cant hardcode my route like v1 or v2 like them, because mine is coming from `getMenuRoute()` and `getSubmenuRoute()` function

```
func main() {
    router := gin.Default()

    // Simple group: v1
    v1 := router.Group("/v1")
    {
        v1.POST("/login", loginEndpoint)
        v1.POST("/submit", submitEndpoint)
        v1.POST("/read", readEndpoint)
    }

    // Simple group: v2
    v2 := router.Group("/v2")
    {
        v2.POST("/login", loginEndpoint)
        v2.POST("/submit", submitEndpoint)
        v2.POST("/read", readEndpoint)
    }

    router.Run(":8080")
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of declaring your `gin.Default()` inside each function you can pass it as a parameter to your router functions.

```
func GetMenuRoutes(router *gin.Engine){
   
    menuRoutes := router.Group("/menu")
    {
        getRoutes := menuRoutes.Group("/get")
        {
            getRoutes.GET("/getallmenus", middlewares.GetAllMenus)
        }
    }
    return 
}
```

or

you can register all these routes on to a main router using
a for loop.

your `main func()` will have the following lines

```
   func main() {
    v1 := getGroup1().Routes()
    v2 := getGroup2().Routes()
    rt := gin.Default()
    for _, a := range v1 {
        {
            rt.Handle(a.Method, a.Path, a.HandlerFunc)
        }
    }
    for _, a := range v2 {
        {
            rt.Handle(a.Method, a.Path, a.HandlerFunc)
        }
    }
    rt.Run(":8080")
   }
```

Comment: but how can get all routes from all function in main.go

Answer (score 1):

@[whitespace](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3956589) 's answer is good. But I found another solution.

So, as you remember, I have a lot of routes coming from 2 functions.

I need to merge them, before main calls all of them

So my first route function from : **menuRoutes.go**

```
    package routes
    
    import(
        "github.com/IamFrost/api-5/pkg/middlewares"
    
        "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
    )
    
    // GetMenuRoutes return a group of routes for menu
    func GetMenuRoutes(router *gin.Engine) *gin.Engine{
    
        menuRoutes := router.Group("/menu")
        {
            getRoutes := menuRoutes.Group("/get")
            {
                getRoutes.GET("/getallmenus", middlewares.GetAllMenus)
            }
        }
    
        return router
    }
```

My second route function from: **submenuRoutes.go**

```
package routes

import(
    "github.com/IamFrost/api-5/pkg/middlewares"

    "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
)


// GetSubMenuRoutes return a group of routes for submenu
func GetSubMenuRoutes(router *gin.Engine) *gin.Engine{

    menuRoutes := router.Group("/submenu")
    {
        getRoutes := menuRoutes.Group("/get")
        {
            getRoutes.GET("/getallsubmenus", middlewares.GetAllSubMenus)
        }
    }
    // router.GET("/getallsubmenus", middlewares.GetAllSubMenus)
    return router
}
```

Finally, I merged both route groups to : **main.go**

```
package main

import(
    "fmt"

    "github.com/IamFrost/api-5/pkg/routes"

    "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
    "github.com/gin-contrib/cors"
)

func main(){
    
    fmt.Println("from main")

    router := gin.Default()

    // router = routes.GetSubMenuRoutes()

    routes.GetMenuRoutes(router)
    routes.GetSubMenuRoutes(router)


    router.Use(cors.Default())
    router.Run(":3000")
}
```